# io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException:JWT signature does not match locally computed signature.JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted

Tags: java, jwt, token

This is the code used in my existing application, but recently I have upgraded the spring boot version. After this I am facing the below issue. jjwtVersion used in this project = "0.9.1"

I am using signing the key using below

```
String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(loginId)
                .claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_LOGIN_ID, loginId).claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_EMAIL_ID, loginId)
                .claim(CommonConstant.JwtClaim.EXPIRED_AT, cal.getTime())
                .claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_OKTA_ID, oktaId)
                .claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_EXPIRES_AT, cal.getTime())
                .claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_BUID,CommonConstant.Buid.KINRAY)
                .claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_USER_TYPE,userDetails.getUserType())
                           .claim(TokenConstants.APP_CLAIM_USER_DETAIL_NUM,userDetails.getUserDetailNum())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, jwtsSigningKey).compact();

        response.setHeader(TokenConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME, token);
```

To create the token using:

```
String signingKeye = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signingKey.getBytes());
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(signingKeye).parseClaimsJws(appToken).getBody();
```

when I authenticate token passed as a header over REST call, authentication fails with SignatureException.

I have tried the signing key in `geyBytes()`, it still has the issue.

Comment: HI Team-Any suggestion on this?

Comment: I have the same error .. Did you fix it?